# INSERT using WHERE clause and cant use UPDATE also

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, where-clause

here is the story, 
- i have customer_database that have serveral customer_id
then 
- every customer_id have their own equipment_database

how can i insert data into equipment_database where the owner is "customer_1"?
im confuse because insert with 'where' **wont be working** here

the example for insert with 'where':

```
INSERT INTO equipment_database (eqp_name) VALUE ('eqp_name_1') WHERE customer_id='1';
```

im also cant do it with update since equipment_database still empty...
any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the update command as stated in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your values saved (rows with customer_id), you need an update operation. Try to do this:

```
UPDATE equipment_database SET eqp_name = 'eqp_name_1' WHERE customer_id='1';
```

I hope it can help you.